# Matlab: Init variable if undefined

Tags: matlab, undefined

How can I declare/assign a variable only if it was never assigned before?

Context:

I'm trying to find k which minimizes a function calculateSomeDistance(k) of k. The minimal distance and the corresponding k value should be available (ie. in scope) for later use. 
How should I declare minDistance so that I can check whether it was already initialized before comparing it to the currently calculated distance?

```
% How should I declare minDistance?
minDistance=undefined; % Doesn't exist.
for ki=1:K,
  distance=calculateSomeDistance(ki);
  if(isUndefined(minDistance) || distance < minDistance)
    minDistance = distance;
    minK = ki;
  end
end
% Here minK and minDistance must be in scope
```

Is there a way to assign a null/undefined value to a variable in matlab/octave and later test for it in order to make the first valid assignment?

PS:
Initializing minDistance to a very large number is very ugly, and not what I'm looking for.

Initializing minDistance when ki is 1 (ie. on first pass) is OK, but still not nice.

Comment: I'd go the `nan`/`isnan()` route in the answer, rather than `exist()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check whether a variable exists using [exist](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/exist.html):

```
if ~exist('minDistance','var')
    minDistance = initValue;
end
```

If you want to have the variable exist in the workspace, but in an undefined state, you can assign `nan` (not a number) and check for that with `isnan`.  This would be similar to the solution you've proposed, with a value type that is explicitly not going to conflict with any valid values of the variable.

Comment: There is a problem with `isnan`, because it only works for double arrays. If you type `isnan({})`, there will be an error:
`Undefined function 'isnan' for input arguments of type 'cell'.`